# Performing operations on all values of a numpy array, referencing i and j

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, indexing

I am trying to improve numpy performance by applying operations on a 2d array, the problem is that the value at each element in the array depends on the i,j location of that element.

Obviously the easy way to do this is to use a nested for-loop, but I was wondering if there might be a better way by referencing np.indices or something along those lines? Here is my 'stupid' code:

```
for J in range(1025):
    for I in range(1025):
        PSI[I][J] = A*math.sin((float(I+1)-.5)*DI)*math.sin((float(J+1)-.5)*DJ)
        P[I][J] = PCF*(math.cos(2.*float(I)*DI)+math.cos(2.*float(J)*DJ))+50000.
```

Comment: Noone explicitly addressed this but using python for loops where you index numpy arrays is losing the speed benefits of numpy being written in C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're doing multiplication among your two arrays, you can use the [outer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) function, after using `arange` to get arrays of your sin/cos.

Something like this (use numpy's trig functions, since they're vectorized)

```
PSI_i = numpy.sin((arange(1,1026)-0.5)*DI)
PSI_j = numpy.sin((arange(1,1026)-0.5)*DJ)
PSI = A*outer(PSI_i, PSI_j)

P_i = numpy.cos(2.*arange(1,1026)*DI)
P_j = numpy.cos(2.*arange(1,1026)*DJ)
P = PCF*outer(P_i, P_j) + 50000
```

If your environment is set up using `from numpy import *` or `from pylab import *`, then you don't need those `numpy.` prefixes before your trig functions. I kept them in to distinguish them from the `math` ones, which won't work for this approach.

Comment: For this particular problem, I think that this is the best solution (+1)

Comment: This is the right approach, but if you're using `numpy.sin` you probably should use `numpy.outer`.

Comment: @tillsten - For whatever it's worth, you can use `outer` for subtraction, division, power, etc as well. E.g. `numpy.subtract.outer(a, b)`, `numpy.power.outer(a, b)`, etc.

Comment: @tillsten - It only works for `ufuncs`, so it's still limited (broadcasting is more general).  It's a handy trick, though. Glad you found it useful!

Answer (score 1):

You can get a grid of the index values with indices:

```
I,J=np.indices(PSI.shape)
#All constants set to one
PSI2=np.sin(I+1-.5)*np.sin(J+1-.5)
print PSI-PSI2 # should be zero.
```

---

I did some timings with ipython:

```
import numpy as np
import math
A = 1
P = 1
DI = 1
DJ = 1

def a():
    PSI=np.zeros((1025,1025))
    for J in range(1025):
        for I in range(1025):
            PSI[I][J] = A*math.sin((float(I+1)-.5)*DI)*math.sin((float(J+1)-.5)*DJ)
%timeit a()

def b():
    PSI=np.zeros((1025,1025))
    for I,J in np.ndindex(*PSI.shape):
        PSI[I,J] = A*math.sin((float(I+1)-.5)*DI)*math.sin((float(J+1)-.5)*DJ)        
%timeit b()

def c():
    I,J=np.indices((1025, 1025))
    P2=A*np.sin((I+1-.5)*DI)*np.sin((J+1-.5)*DJ)    
%timeit c()

def d():
    PSI_i = np.sin((np.arange(1,1026)-0.5)*DI)
    PSI_j = np.sin((np.arange(1,1026)-0.5)*DJ)
    PSI = A*np.outer(PSI_i, PSI_j)    
%timeit d()
```

The result is not at all surprising on my machine:

```
1 loops, best of 3: 1.75 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 3.51 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 77.1 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 7.16 ms per loop
```

Comment: You're not actually calling the functions.  You need `%timeit a()`, etc., not `%timeit a`.

Comment: Doing the timings correctly, I got that the solution with `np.outer` takes approximately 0.009s, the solution with indices takes ~0.12s the nested loops take 1.4s and `np.ndindex` takes a whopping 3.28s.  I would like to know why `np.ndindex` is so slow -- I would have expected it to come between the other solutions, but I've deleted my answer anyway ;).  (I guess this shows why we profile).

Comment: @mgilson, the reason `ndindex` is so slow is that it returns a python iterator. `a = np.ndindex((10, 10)); print a.next(); print a.next()`.

Comment: @senderle -- Interesting.  I thought that it would have returned a generator, but I guess that's what I get for not reading the docs carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ndenumerate function of numpy, which returns the value as well as the indices:

```
>>> a
array([[5, 5, 5],
       [1, 2, 3]])


>>> for index, value in numpy.ndenumerate(a):
...     print index, value

(0, 0) 5
(0, 1) 5
(0, 2) 5
(1, 0) 1
(1, 1) 2
(1, 2) 3
```

Comment: That's the way to do for decent-sized Python lists. But when using NumPy, that's to be avoided, both to not ruin the performance advantage of unboxed+packed data and C functions and because you're usually using those for *huge* amounts of data (OP's example already has a million elements).