# Speed up operation on nested python array

Tags: python, arrays, performance

I'm working with a nested array. I need to apply a rather simple but costly arithmetic operation on each element of this array.

Below is the `MWE`, where the "second block" is the one that takes up most of the time (it will run thousands of times).

The first and second blocks *need* to be separated since the first one is only processed once, given that the **real** way to obtain `a,b,c` is very costly time-wise.

I'm not sure how I could improve the performance of this operation applied on each element of the nested array. Surely `numpy` would do this much faster, but I'm not much familiarized with broadcasting operations on arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import time


# Generate some random data.
N = 100
x, y, z = [np.random.uniform(0., 10., N) for _ in range(3)]

# Grid of values in 2 dimensions.
M = 200
p_lst, q_lst = np.linspace(0., 50., M), np.linspace(0., 25., M)

# Define empty nested list to be filled below.
# The shape is given by the length of the lists defined above.
abc_lst = [[[] for _ in p_lst] for _ in q_lst]

# First block. This needs to be separated from the block below.
# Fill nested list with values.
for i, p in enumerate(p_lst):
    for j, q in enumerate(q_lst):

        # a,b,c are obtained via some complicated function of p,q.
        # This is just for the purpose of this example.
        a, b, c = 1.*p, 1.*q, p+q

        # Store in nested list.
        abc_lst[i][j] = [a, b, c]

# Second block <-- THIS IS THE BOTTLENECK
tik = time.time()
# Apply operation on nested list.
lst = []
for i in range(len(p_lst)):
    for j in range(len(q_lst)):

        # Extract a,b,c values from nested list.
        a, b, c = abc_lst[i][j]

        # Apply operation. This is the *actual* operation
        # I need to apply.
        d = sum(abs(a*x + y*b + c*z))

        # Store value.
        lst.append(d)

print time.time() - tik
```

Comment: Avoid loops inside loops by flattening your 2D array into a 1D and reshaping at the end. It will be MUCH faster already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10821477/1391441), using the [np.outer()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) function.

It only takes a bit of re-arranging of the first block, and the second block runs many many times faster.

```
# First block. Store a,b,c separately.
a_lst, b_lst, c_lst = [], [], []
for i, p in enumerate(p_lst):
    for j, q in enumerate(q_lst):

        # a,b,c are obtained via some complicated function of p,q.
        # This is just for the purpose of this example.
        a_lst.append(1.*p)
        b_lst.append(1.*q)
        c_lst.append(p+q)

# As arrays.
a_lst, b_lst, c_lst = np.asarray(a_lst), np.asarray(b_lst), np.asarray(c_lst)

# Second block.
# Apply operation on nested list using np.outer.
lst = np.sum(abs(np.outer(a_lst, x) + np.outer(b_lst, y) + np.outer(c_lst, z)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think two sets of loops are necessary.  Just collapse into one:

```
## Always pre-allocate with zeros if possible...not just empty lists
lst = np.zeros(M*M)

# First block. This one runs fast.
tik = time.time()
# Fill nested list with values.
for i, p in enumerate(p_lst):
    for j, q in enumerate(q_lst):

        # a,b,c are obtained via some complicated function of p,q.
        # This is just for the purpose of this example.
        a, b, c = 1.*p, 1.*q, p+q

        # Don't store in nested list, just calculate
        ##abc_lst[i][j] = [a, b, c]  
        lst[i*M+j] = (sum(abs(a*x + y*b + c*z)))
```

Comment: Thank you gariepy! Unfortunately the blocks *need* to be separated because the first one is only processed once. I've edited my question to reflect this.